# Why is the result of pandas.Series([numpy.nan]).astype("bool") is True?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering why the result of

`pandas.Series([numpy.nan]).astype("bool")`

is `True`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because `np.nan` objects are themselves *truthy*:

```
>>> bool(np.nan)
True
```

Comment: it seems very interesting to me. I was guessing it to be `False`